# Continuously monitor the postfix Mailqueue (real time)

Tags: postfix, monitoring, realtime

Is there a command to look at the Mailqueue of Postfix in real time.

I know of the commands, `postqueue -p` and `mailq`.

What I am looking for is real time monitoring of the queue. Similar to when I monitor a log with `tail -f`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I know of the commands, postqueue -p and mailq.

You can run either of those through `watch`:

```
$  watch -n1 mailq
```

Comment: If you want to filter the output using `grep`, you will have to specify the command inside quotes like this: `watch 'mailq | grep "[^A-F0-9]"'`.